# Didn't get mortarboard badge?

Tags: support, bug, badges

Yesterday (Feb 11th) I gained 240 reputation, but I didn't get the Mortarboard badge.

> Earned at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day

Anyone know why this may be?

Comment: It can take a day or two. Give it some time.

Comment: Don't despair. Mortarboard is pretty easy to get (on this site... SO is a bit harder)

Comment: I've waited a week and still not gotten mine.

Comment: Now it's nine days. I'd like the badge. It's a good one. I had +216. Why no badge yet? (June 5th on my history to verify, should you care to.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The association bonus doesn't count towards Mortarboard (or the day's cap). Sorry, but you'll have to get 200 from upvotes, accepts, and bounties.

Comment: Also worth noting that you only get the badge once. As per: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4728/21267