# After nine days, still didn't get badge

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/didnt-get-mortarboard-badge) says wait a couple days. It's been **nine days**. I'd like the badge. It's a good one. I had +216. Why no badge yet? (June 5th on my history to verify, should you care to.) There was no "association" figure included in the tally. It's legit. I haven't had a badge take this long to show up. Please advise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only earn [Mortarboard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard) *once* - the **first** time you earn 200 points in a day.

If you pull that stunt 50 times, you'll get another badge: [Epic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/epic).

A [Legendary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary) few manage to do it 150 times...

Comment: Ahhh. Okay. Thanks for the clarification. I'm more ignorant than I realized.

Comment: @shog, there's only one legendary (yet).

Comment: @MeatTrademark RE: "I'm more ignorant than I realized." You have not earned [that one](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/tumbleweed) yet.

Comment: @MeatTrademark: “ I'm more ignorant than I realized.” Yes, you are. Not my words: *[the words of science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)*.

Comment: Whoah, @PaulD.Waite, we don't gotta get all D-K on this but [I trust you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_syndrome).